# How to get uncommon elements from two arrays using java

Tags: java

I have two string arrays

```
array1={"Hardware Docs","Customer Data","Customer Docs","Commit Reviews","Product Planning Docs","Business Operations ","Proprietary"};
array2={"Hardware Docs","Customer Docs"};
```

I want uncommon strings from both of these arrays.can anyone suggest how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by uncommon? Present in one and not the other?

Comment: Convert array to list, then refer post in the comment.

Answer (score -1):

```
    String [] array1={"Hardware Docs","Customer Data","Customer Docs","Commit Reviews","Product Planning Docs","Business Operations ","Proprietary"};
    String[] array2={"Hardware Docs","Customer Docs"};

    ArrayList<String> filter1 = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String str1: array1){
        boolean match = false;
        for(String str2: array2){
            if(str1.equals(str2))
                match = true;
        }
        if(!match)
            filter1.add(str1);
    }
```

but this is soo brute force. If performance is important for you, you should look for better solutions

Comment: How do we write same code in javascript?